# python3.11 selenium and flask not working on my pc

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, flask

```
has been deprecated, please use an Options object
  firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/corde/OneDrive/Desktop/my_scripts/jcpennyauto.py", line 55, in <module>
    fill_registration_form()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/corde/OneDrive/Desktop/my_scripts/jcpennyauto.py", line 17, in fill_registration_form
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile, executable_path=geckodriver_path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'firefox_profile'
```

I've tried everything, I made a simple selenium program to automate form filling.

I tried changing from `options()`. I used ChatGPT to debug and to show it the error, it helped me rewrite the code but no luck. I did a complete uninstall of selenium again no luck.